# How to display a list of multiple ggplots in a matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an object `myplots` that contains 9 `geom_point` + `geom_smooth` as shown below

[image]

I tried both approaches `par(mfrow=c(3,3))` and `layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 3, 3, byrow=TRUE))` to display them in a grid of 3x3 but none of them worked. The plots were displayed individually instead of in one page/window.

What did I do wrong and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would to be use the `cowplot` package. The function `cowplot::plot_grid()` makes it very easy to do this sort of thing. Just pass your list of plots to the `plotlist` argument, and specify the `nrow` and/or `ncol` argument to choose how you want to arrange them.
There's so much that can be done with this package and its much easier than base graphics, so I recommend using it, unless you are worried about adding another dependency to your code.

Here's an example I work up below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20))
x <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_smooth()
l <- rep(list(x), 9)

plot_grid(plotlist = l, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer with a concrete example! Thanks a lot